# Is there a faster way to check existence of child elements under the document element of an XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have to analyze a lot of XML files in my current project.
I get the XML files as  a `string` object.
I wrote a method to check if the XML String contains any data.

```
private bool ContainsXmlData(string xmlString)
```

{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlString))
   return false;
  XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
  try
  {
   Doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
  }
  catch (XmlException)
  {
   return false;
  }
  if (!Doc.DocumentElement.HasChildNodes)
   return false;
  return true;
 }

Is there a way to perform this check faster? Is it possible to check this without using an `XmlDocument`?

***EDIT***

I have made a new method with `XPathDocument` and `XPathNavigator`. Thanks Mitch Wheat and Kragen :)

```
private bool ContainsXmlData(string xmlString)
```

{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlString))
   return false;
  try
  {
   StringReader Reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
   XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(Reader);
   XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
   XPathNodeIterator iter = nav.Select("*/*");
   return (iter.Count > 0) ? true : false;
  }
  catch (XmlException)
  {
   return false;
  }
 }

Comment: Does your `xmlString` always have the same root node?  e.g., `<myRoot></myRoot>`?  Or can the root be different?

Comment: @DHoerster It can be different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XPathDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx) provides fast, read-only access to the contents of an XML document using XPath.

Or use an [XmlTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) (**fastest**) which provides fast, forward-only, non-cached access to XML data.

- [At-A-Glance: XmlReader vs. XPathNavigator vs. XmlDocument](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AtAGlanceXmlReaderVsXPathNavigatorVsXmlDocument.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately XPath is no option, since the name of the document element and child elements is not known at this time.  
I'll check out the XmlTextReader. Thanks for the link with further information :)

Comment: @peter you don't need to know the name of the child elements - you can use wildcards. I believe `*/*` should do the trick (not tested)

Comment: @kragen thanks for the tip. didn't think about that. will post my solution as soon i have it finished